# taking length of predefined string vs getting one from input

Tags: c, string, c99

I seem to be unable to understand why do these two cases behave differently:

```
const char* TEXT = "hello world!";
int length = (int) strlen(TEXT);
char* array[length];
```

this is ok, however this one:

```
char* text;
scanf("%[^\n]s", text);
// input "hello world!" and press enter
int length = (int) strlen(text);
char* array[length];
```

ends with a segmentation fault

what am I missing?

Comment: You have not allocated space for the second string, so you're trying to put the input, well, God knows where.

Comment: In the second example you have a pointer `text`, but *where does it point?*

Comment: In your second case, your have declared `text` as a pointer, but haven't pointed it at anything. You need to define a memory buffer (character array) somewhere and point `text` to it.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the format `%[^\n]s` is most likely wrong. It reads a line and then the `scanf` function expects a literal `s` in the input. I guess you want only `%[^\n]`.

Comment: Why are you casting the result from `strlen` instead of declaring `length` as an `size_t`?

Comment: FYI, `char *array[length];` does not define a pointer to an array that can hold `length` characters. It defines an array of pointers, none of which have been initialized to point to anything. It is likely not what you want unless the subsequent processing involves using one string for each character in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `scanf` call, `text` parameter, you do not allocate any memory. You also do not initialize the variable to a value. This results in `scanf` writing to random memory, which causes your segmentation fault.

To fix this issue you need to allocate a buffer of a reasonable size:

```
char* text = malloc(1024);
```

`1024` is the maximum size that you expect the input data to be. This, however, still leaves the code vulnerable to buffer overflows. To prevent buffer overflows you can inform `scanf` that `text` is of a certain size; look for the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621973/2548287)

If you do not want to allocate the memory yourself, `scanf` can do it for you:

> ---
>
> Note that the POSIX 2008 (2013) version of the
>   [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
>   family of functions supports a format modifier `m` (an
>   assignment-allocation character) for string inputs (`%s`, `%c`, `%[`).
>   Instead of taking a `char *` argument, it takes a `char **` argument,
>   and it allocates the necessary space for the value it reads:
>
> ```
> char *buffer = 0;
> if (sscanf(data, "%ms", &buffer) == 1)
> {
>     printf("String is: <<%s>>\n", buffer);
>     free(buffer);
> }
> ```
>
> If the `sscanf()` function fails to satisfy all the conversion
>   specifications, then all the memory it allocated for `%ms`-like
>   conversions is freed before the function returns.